# get specific elements from a matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, subset

I have a matrix `ALL` that is `94968x8` and I want to create a new matrix `B`, but with some conditions.

At the 2nd column I have months(1-12) and at the 4th column I have hours(0-23).

So, I want the elements from the 5th column , if (for example) it's January(1) and midnight(0).

My matrix:

[image: Matrix A]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using logical indexing:

```
MONTH_COL_NUM = 2;
HOUR_COL_NUM = 4;
SELECT_COL = 5;
B = A(A(:,MONTH_COL_NUM) == 1 & A(:,HOUR_COL_NUM) == 0, SELECT_COL);
```

Comment: That works perfect, thank you!
And is it possible to create a loop which will calculate these matrices for each hour per each month?

Comment: @M.D.Tsia Yes, that is possible.